# SSRS: How to SUM row data based on condition

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have table of the structure:-

Row1:- not inside Details group.

Row 2:- Dynamically populating row. with sequence as:-

A  **X**

A1   1

A2   2

B **Y**

B1   30

B2   40

I need to calculate value of Y(which is Value of B1+B2)
and X(which is Value of A1+A2)

Also in Row 1 I need to display X+Y.

Please note:- I am not sure about the number of rows which can be there in either A or B. So Y can be B1+B2+B3.... so on.

Also A and B are being populated by the same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear as to how your data is set up so I can't give a good answer but for SUMming based on a condition you'd want to do something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!A.Value = "X", FIELDS!UNKNOWN?.Value, 0))
```

This would SUM all of the `UNKNOWN` field when `field A` = `x`.

If this isn't what you were looking for, try adding your field names and relate them to your values.